# Задача "Банкомат"

Tags: c++

Надо написать программу, которая выдаёт из банкомата запрошенную сумму денег (кратную 10) в имеющихся купюрах (100 рублей, 50 рублей, 10 рублей). Сумму необходимо выдавать по возможности наиболее крупными купюрами. Сумма не будет превышать 20000 руб.Sample Input 1:1000; Sample Output 1:
100: 10
50: 0
10: 0
Sample Input 2:180;Sample Output 2:
100: 1
50: 1
10: 3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    int banknotes[] = { 100,50,10 };
    int money;
    cin >> money;
    int Cash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Cash += money / banknotes[i];
        money = money % banknotes[i];
    }

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос в следующем, не могу вывести так как показано сверху, как исправить, буду благодарен, потому что новичок в программирований на С ++, поэтому такие глупые вопроси.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int banknotes[] = { 100,50,10 };
int money;
cin >> money;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << banknotes[i] << ": " << money / banknotes[i] << "  ";
    money %= banknotes[i];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,чет тупанул